# Can't locate Git.pm in @INC

Tags: git, perl

When I run `git add -p`, I see:

```
Can't locate Git.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4
/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.12
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at
/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-add--interactive line 7.
```

I just got a new mac running 10.8.4. I installed the XCode Command Line Tools.

Comment: Did you setup Git as well?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Did you already have Git installed? If not, how did you install it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On OSX (and Homebrew) I fixed this by simply reinstalling:

```
$ brew uninstall git
$ brew install git
```

Answer (score 3):

On macOS Mojave, git perl lib is in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/perl`. So, it can be fixed by:

```
export PERLLIB=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/perl:$PERLLIB
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Finally I had resolved it by installing `git` from source and having my installation in my PATH rather the one from XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Git.pm is usually shipped as part of your Git installation, not as part of Perl.

As a result, it will be located somewhere relative to the `git` program. Try looking in a lib directory nearby whatever the output of `which git` is. For example, if `which git` returns `/opt/local/bin/git` the try looking under the directory `/opt/local/lib`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue on my Mac OS 10.9.4, and fixed it with the following command:

```
$ sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core /usr/share/
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed via SymLink. I just couldn't be asked to do that, but instead I reinstall git using `brew uninstall git` and `brew install git`, which does the trick for me.