# No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I have been struggling with this for a few hours. I am on a Mac using Yosemite. I had homebrew installed, and was using git just fine. I tried doing `$git add -i` and I got this error:

> Can't locate Git.pm in @INC (@INC contains:

So I followed the instructions here:
[Can't locate Git.pm in @INC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736330/cant-locate-git-pm-in-inc)

`$brew uninstall git` worked fine, but after I tried to `$brew install git` I've been stuck in a terrible cycle.

```
% brew install git

Error: git-git already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink git'
% brew unlink git
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git
% brew link git
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git
% git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
% brew upgrade git
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
git 2.2.2
Error: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/git is not a valid keg
% brew install git
Error: git-git already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink git'
%
```

I just want to get homebrew & git back to normal and linked to the correct repo again. I'm really rough around the edges at this stuff, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. It's just a mention about xcode being outdated:

`% brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Your Xcode (6.1) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 6.1.1.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.`

Comment: Ok, are you able to run `brew update` without error?

Comment: Yes, it seems so
`% brew update
Updated Homebrew from fe048363 to a41d46bb.
==> New Formulae
why3
==> Updated Formulae
cmake      galen   juju        slimerjs     tippecanoe  xulrunner`

Comment: Hrmmm what's the output of `type git`?

Comment: it outputs:
`git is /usr/bin/git`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Give another go at force removing the brewed version of git

```
brew uninstall --force git
```

Then cleanup any older versions and clear the brew cache

```
brew cleanup -s git
```

Remove any dead symlinks

```
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
```

Then try reinstalling git

```
brew install git
```

If that doesn't work, I'd remove that installation of Homebrew altogether and reinstall it. If you haven't placed anything else in your `brew --prefix` directory (`/usr/local` by default), you can simply `rm -rf $(brew --prefix)`. Otherwise the Homebrew wiki recommends using a script at https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223#file-uninstall_homebrew-sh

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling homebrew is the only thing that got me out of this mess.

Comment: @MattFlorence how did you uninstall homebrew? everywhere i go says you must have git installed to remove homebrew.

Comment: In new newest os X I have: "Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave."

Comment: `brew cleanup --force` doesn't exist anymore, just use `brew cleanup -s git`

Comment: also `brew prune` does not exist anymore, use `brew cleanup --prune-prefix`

Comment: On my machine it was "brew cleanup -s ..." without "--force"

Answer (score 6):

Os X Mojave 10.14 has:

> Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on
> Mojave.

Solution. Go to

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

location and install the package manually. And brew will start working and we can run:

```
brew uninstall --force git
brew cleanup -s git
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
brew install git
```

Comment: `brew prune` does not exist, use `brew cleanup --prune-prefix`

Comment: Error: invalid option: --force

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar issue while installing "Lua" in OS X using homebrew. I guess it could be useful for other users facing similar issue in homebrew.

On running the command:

> `$ brew install lua`

The command returned an error:

> Error: /usr/local/opt/lua is not a valid keg
>   (in general the error can be of /usr/local/opt/ is not a valid keg

FIXED it by deleting the file/directory it is referring to, i.e., deleting the "/usr/local/opt/lua" file.

> root-user # rm -rf /usr/local/opt/lua

And then running the brew install command returned success.