# MacOS delete php 5.6 and leave only php 7

Tags: php, macos, unix

I have 2 versions of php installed on my macOS. When I restart the computer it is set by default to php 5.6 (I have already twice installed php 7 and it is available only till the next restart). How can I set the default to be 7.0? what should I do in .bash_profile? (to what should I change the home path of the php variable?)

Comment: How did you install php? homebrew, compiled from source, etc.

Comment: homebrew. I am using Postman and want to send/ receive json requests for my API but I get the notification(error):  $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated, So I want to delete the 5.6 version

Comment: Have you tried `brew uninstall php56`?

Comment: I get the following error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php

Comment: while php -v return the 5.6 version.

Comment: Maybe you can try the solution here, but with `php56` instead of `git`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225045/no-such-keg-usr-local-cellar-git#28240901

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: unfortunately no. I had problems with a lot of configuration files and I had more reasons to reinstall my macOS and installed php 7.0

Answer (score 2):

If you install PHP with Homebrew, you might need to unlink the 5.6 version. Like:

```
$ brew unlink php56
```

Then you may start to install PHP 7.2

You can get more information from my article:

[Upgrade PHP version from 5.6 to 7.2 on macOS Sierra (10.12)](https://charles4code.blogspot.com/2018/06/upgrade-php-version-from-56-to-72-on.html)