# Downgrade Python Version 3.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

I am trying to downgrade my python version to 3.6. Currently, I am running python version 3.7.2. I've looked at other posts who have encountered the same issue, but I have tried some of the solutions and they don't seem to work (I am running on Mac OS).

When I run the following in terminal I receive the following error:

```
MacBookPro:~ robertg21$ brew unlink python
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python
```

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Yes, I used homebrew.

Comment: Perhaps use force to remove your current installed version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225045/no-such-keg-usr-local-cellar-git/28240901#28240901

Comment: Also, include homebrew as a tag to your question, since this isn't a question about python, it is really a question about homebrew.

Comment: Why not just install python 3.6 separately instead of downgrading 3.7 ?

Comment: When running it in terminal python how will python default to version 3.6?