# BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.1 using ruby-build 20191124) when installing ruby-2.4.0 with rbenv in OSX catalina(10.15.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, anaconda, rbenv

I tried a lot of things from online forums. But never worked. Installed Xcode to see if it works. But it doesn't.

At first, there was an issue with the C executables at the time of the OpenSSL installation. But later, I found from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1446630/rbenv-install-2-3-1-gives-build-failed-os-x-10-14-5-and-configure-error-c-c?newreg=8136241215494206896374aa481e6c3f), the error occurred because of Anaconda installation. So I uninstalled anaconda and tried to install again.

But now it is throwing a different error.

> ➜  ~ rbenv install 2.4.0 Downloading openssl-1.1.0j.tar.gz...
>   -> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/31bec6c203ce1a8e93d5994f4ed304c63ccf07676118b6634edded12ad1b3246
>   Installing openssl-1.1.0j... Installed openssl-1.1.0j to
>   /Users/akashpinnaka/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0
>
> Downloading ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2...
>   -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2 Installing ruby-2.4.0... ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
>
> BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.1 using ruby-build 20191124)
>
> Inspect or clean up the working tree at
>   /var/folders/xs/gy8wglwj22g9lbhqfv9mwp7m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20191205014031.81437.0Fmlfl
>   Results logged to
>   /var/folders/xs/gy8wglwj22g9lbhqfv9mwp7m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20191205014031.81437.log
>
> Last 10 log lines: num2int.c:64:5: note: to match this '('
>       sprintf(buf, "%"PRI_LL_PREFIX"u", NUM2ULL(num));
>       ^ /usr/local/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:27: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'   **builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str),
>   __VA_ARGS**)
>                             ^ 190 warnings and 2 errors generated. make[2]: *** [num2int.o] Error 1 make[1](https://superuser.com/questions/1446630/rbenv-install-2-3-1-gives-build-failed-os-x-10-14-5-and-configure-error-c-c?newreg=8136241215494206896374aa481e6c3f): *** [ext/-test-/num2int/all]
>   Error 2 make: *** [build-ext] Error 2

Did anyone face this problem before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Adding the last few lines in the logfile. Most of them look like errors in C lang

```
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:354:36: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
         strtouq(const char *__str, char **__endptr, int __base);
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:354:36: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
         strtouq(const char *__str, char **__endptr, int __base);
                                          ^
                                            _Nullable 
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:354:36: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
         strtouq(const char *__str, char **__endptr, int __base);
                                          ^
                                            _Nonnull 
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:356:13: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
extern char *suboptarg;         /* getsubopt(3) external variable */
            ^
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:356:13: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
extern char *suboptarg;         /* getsubopt(3) external variable */
            ^
              _Nullable 
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:356:13: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
extern char *suboptarg;         /* getsubopt(3) external variable */
            ^
              _Nonnull 
num2int.c:56:21: error: expected ')'
    sprintf(buf, "%"PRI_LL_PREFIX"d", NUM2LL(num));
                    ^
num2int.c:56:5: note: to match this '('
    sprintf(buf, "%"PRI_LL_PREFIX"d", NUM2LL(num));
    ^
/usr/local/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:27: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                          ^
num2int.c:64:21: error: expected ')'
    sprintf(buf, "%"PRI_LL_PREFIX"u", NUM2ULL(num));
                    ^
num2int.c:64:5: note: to match this '('
    sprintf(buf, "%"PRI_LL_PREFIX"u", NUM2ULL(num));
    ^
/usr/local/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:27: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                          ^
190 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [num2int.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/-test-/num2int/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Here is the pate bin for the detailed errors:
https://pastebin.com/wzLGzvC5

**EDIT:**

> $ which clang

```
/usr/bin/clang
```

> $ brew ls

```
adns        gnutls      libksba     openssl     ruby
autoconf    icu4c       libtasn1    openssl@1.1 ruby-build
automake    libassuan   libtool     p11-kit     sqlite
awk     libevent    libunistring    pinentry    unbound
coreutils   libffi      libusb      pkg-config  zlib
gettext     libgcrypt   libyaml     postgresql
gmp     libgpg-error    nettle      rbenv
gnupg       libidn2     npth        readline
```

> $ brew doctor

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

After I deleted the files suggested by `brew doctor`

Few lines from

> $ ls -la /usr/local/include

```
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  270 akashpinnaka  admin  8640 Dec 24 11:30 .
drwxr-xr-x   18 root          wheel   576 Dec  5 11:15 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 akashpinnaka  admin     0 Dec  5 10:11 .keepme
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          admin    85 Dec  5 11:21 AppleTextureEncoder.h -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AppleTextureEncoder.h
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          admin    78 Dec  5 11:21 AssertMacros.h -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AssertMacros.h
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          admin    78 Dec  5 11:21 Availability.h -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/Availability.h
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          admin    86 Dec  5 11:21 AvailabilityInternal.h -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          admin    84 Dec  5 11:21 AvailabilityMacros.h -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root          admin    86 Dec  5 11:21 AvailabilityVersions.h -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityVersions.h
```

Comment: What's in the logfile? Please add the content to the question.

Comment: @Casper, logfile has 20 million lines, I can post the last few lines

Comment: Added few errors.

Comment: @Casper Added pastebin with more detailed errors

Comment: Gcc would be much more preferable as compiler I think. Not an OSX expert but something is screwed up on catalina. Did you try these suggestions? https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1361

Comment: I tried it. But didn't work

Comment: Create a new issue. They should be better equipped to help. If you find a solution you can post it here also.

Answer (score 4):

First, let trim your log to the significant part:

```
num2int.c:56:21: error: expected ')'
    sprintf(buf, "%"PRI_LL_PREFIX"d", NUM2LL(num));
                    ^
num2int.c:56:5: note: to match this '('
    sprintf(buf, "%"PRI_LL_PREFIX"d", NUM2LL(num));
    ^
/usr/local/include/secure/_stdio.h:47:27: note: expanded from macro 'sprintf'
  __builtin___sprintf_chk (str, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Basically, this says that there was an error while expanding a macro to some line in file `num2int.c`. So, where is does that macro come from? The log says that the macro was defined in file `/usr/local/include/secure/_stdio.h`.

This file correspond to a locally installed package, most probably added through `brew` (it could also have been installed by some application installed with a package installer, but this appears less probable). I have not found yet to which package that file belongs (don't have it on my computer and havn't found any reference to it on Google), but `_stdio.h` files are rather exceptionnal, so I believe that it might be related to `brew`'s private GCC. Yet, `ruby-build` (when executed though `rb-env install`) prefer to use XCode's `clang` compiler, which might not support some syntax extension supported by `brew`'s GCC.

In short, you end up loading in Apple's `clang` some local include file that use some syntax thaat is not compatible with that compiler.

**What to do now?**

You must determine if the `/usr/local/include/secure/` directory is actually useful. Maybe, this is related to a program that you no longer use… I can't tell you exactly what to do about this, but here are some ideas:

- Check if either `secure` or `secure/_stdio.h` is a symlink (i.e.: `ls -l /usr/local/include/secure/`). If they have been installed by `brew`, they should point to somewhere under `../Cellar/<package-name>`. If there are, maybe you could consider uninstalling that package…
- Run `brew doctor` and check for "Unexpected header files".

Ideally, you want to end up deleting that directory… If you are not certain either it is a good idea, then you may consider moving it temporarilly out of the `include` directory, for example by doing the following:

```
mkdir /usr/local/include.disabled
mv /usr/local/include/secure /usr/local/include.disabled/secure

# Compile ruby

mv /usr/local/include.disabled/secure /usr/local/include/secure
rm -rf /usr/local/include.disabled
```

If none of this works, please post the output of the following commands to a pastebin:

```
which clang

brew doctor

brew ls

ls -la /usr/local/include
```

**How to move all OSX SDK include files out of `local/include`**

I think the following command should be enough to move all include files pointing to the OSX SDK out of the `/usr/local/include` directory (my uncertainty here is related to either sub-directories were themselves symlinked, or if it is the content of these subdirectories that is symlinke… I assumed the first, and this oneliner script will miss directories if they are of the second type).

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/include.disabled/
find /usr/local/include/ -depth 1 -lname '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/*' -exec mv '{}' /usr/local/include.disabled/ ';'
```

Run these commands, then execute `ls -la /usr/local/include` again… There should be much less content in it. Do you still have a `secure` directory there?

And most importanly, can you now get through your original build?

Comment: Found something really interesting… Found this 7 years old gist with the very same error, at the same line in the same file (except that it is in `/usr/include/secure`, not `local`): https://gist.github.com/mitchty/4187027. This makes me think that you might have a copy under `/src/local/include/` of some very old header files from Apple… Could it be that you still have some brew's `apple-gcc*` formula installed?

Comment: I think the second “mv” command should copy the “secure” dir back to its original place, but doesn’t.

Comment: Indeed... Fixed!

Comment: Thanks for responding @jwatkins. I updated the question with the details you asked

Comment: I had the same issue, and i deleted everthing inside include and then was able to compile ruby

Comment: Ok... Nothing fishy installed in brew, but I'm very surprised by the content of your include directory. It appears to contain a full copy of OSX SDK include files. Personally, it is the first time I ever see this, and it certainly makes sense to think that this might explain your issue...

Comment: Any news? Have you tried removing OS X include files, as I explained previously?

Comment: @jwatkins I did. But it didn't work. So the only option I found is to factory reset the OS

Comment: You save my life @jwatkins. My problem was a symlink on /usr/local/include after a move out this folder. All works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I was facing a similar issue and can recommend the approach below that's related to **binutils** needing to be **uninstall**ed first. What worked for me:

```
brew uninstall binutils
# Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.33.1... (134 files, 167.6MB)

rbenv install 2.6.5 && rbenv local 2.6.5 ;
# Downloading openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz...
# -> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/1e3a91bc1f9dfce01af26026f856e064eab4c8ee0a8f457b5ae30b40b8b711f2
# Installing openssl-1.1.1d...
# Installed openssl-1.1.1d to /Users/auser/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5

# Downloading ruby-2.6.5.tar.bz2...
# -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.5.tar.bz2
# Installing ruby-2.6.5...
# ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
# Installed ruby-2.6.5 to /Users/auser/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5
```

Prior to this the I was also getting a number of varying messages in **ruby-build.log** - with the last being:

```
# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

A number of other steps that I took as part of my homebrew stepup (prior to uninstall) included:

```
brew install perl ruby rbenv
# // UPDATE PATHs with suggestions made by brew during install
which awk perl
# /usr/local/bin/awk
# /usr/local/bin/perl
# ^^^ IN SHORT ALL PATHs should be with /usr/local/opt OR /usr/local/bin
```

You can re-install binutils again after as needed and remember to repeat the uninstallation with any future `rbenv install` version(s) that you're likely to re-execute (note to self).

PS - tested on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76) successfully installing both 2.4.0 & 2.6.5

Comment: Just removing homebrews binutils solved this issue for me, when trying to build openssl 1.1.1g for ruby 2.7.1, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run these commands:

```
brew unlink gawk
brew reinstall awk
awk
```

before running `rbenv install 2.4.0`

Comment: Tried it. Still the same error. When I `brew unlink gawk`, it says `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gawk`. Thanks for responding

Comment: Same here - does not work (`Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gawk`)

Comment: Maybe issue is with your local brew installations can you please try this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225045/no-such-keg-usr-local-cellar-git @iKK