# Ruby 2.3.8 installation fails on MacOS with rbenv as it is showing build failure while installing openssl

Tags: ruby, macos, build, openssl, rbenv

I have macos monterey M1 pro chip, and while installing the ruby version 2.3.8 through rbenv it is failing as it is showing a build error while installing OpenSSL.

```html
% rbenv install 2.3.8                      
To follow progress, use 'tail -f /var/folders/qm/hl42kf3n21l484mj_trgmn_40000gq/T/ruby-build.20220902142349.96411.log' or pass --verbose
Downloading openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/ecd0c6ffb493dd06707d38b14bb4d8c2288bb7033735606569d8f90f89669d16
Installing openssl-1.0.2u...

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220825)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/qm/hl42kf3n21l484mj_trgmn_40000gq/T/ruby-build.20220902142349.96411.dXy6dR
Results logged to /var/folders/qm/hl42kf3n21l484mj_trgmn_40000gq/T/ruby-build.20220902142349.96411.log

Last 10 log lines:
      _dgram_write in libcrypto.a(bss_dgram.o)
      _RAND_query_egd_bytes in libcrypto.a(rand_egd.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [link_a.darwin] Error 1
make[3]: *** [do_darwin-shared] Error 2
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

I have tried the solution posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483699/ruby-2-6-0-installation-fails-on-macos-with-rbenv) stackoverflow link, but there is no Binutils present in my homebrew so it didn't help. I have searched on the internet a lot and couldn't able to find any possible solution.
I pasted the exact error and logs. Let me know if anyone faced this same issue before?

Comment: As far as I remember I couldn't get any ruby < 2.7 to work on M1 chip unless installed as some workaround way using rosetta.

Answer (score 0):

`RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.3.8`