# How to resolve error "command not found: pod" despite cocoapods successful install?

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods

I have run `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Lots of gems installed and no error shown. But despite that, when I run `pod setup`, I keep getting error "command not found: pod". I tried rerun the cocoapods installation. And the pod command still can't be run. How to fix this? I use MacOS.

Comment: In my case I did reinstall cocoapods next way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28240901/5790492

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately, I decided to uninstall every gems and every ruby version in my Mac, and start over. I see tutorial from [here](https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-your-mac-everything-you-need-to-get-going/), and basically the important things when installing Cocoapods are:

1> Make sure Homebrew is installed. Or run this command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2> Install Ruby using Homebrew, without `sudo`.

```
brew install ruby
```

3> Important: add path below to your PATH environment variable on your zshrc profile.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

4> Reload the zshrc profile so the newly added path can take effect.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

5> Make sure the newly installed Ruby is in effect.

```
which ruby
```

this should return `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`

6> Install cocoapods using Ruby, again, *WITHOUT* sudo.

```
gem install cocoapods
```

7> Test that the cocoapods correctly installed and the Gemfile correctly built by run simple command:

```
pod
```

If this returns something other than "command not found" error, you installed it correctly.

Troubleshoot:

1> Error "access not found" or similar when installing cocoapods.

Answer: you most likely still using the "system Ruby", which has different place of gems installation, and your user account likely won't have access to the path.

Try to run `which ruby`.

If it says: `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`, then this is already newly installed ruby, and there's nothing wrong with this process.

If it says: `usr/bin/ruby`, then this is system Ruby. You need to run step 3 and step 4 to make sure the new path is activated.

2> Running `pod` gives error: "command not found".

This is most probably caused by the same path issue thing as problem #1. Just retry step 3 and 4.

3> Running `pod` gives error: "Gemfile not found".

This is most probably caused by you installing cocoapods using `sudo`, which will complicates the hell of your installation. This causes the Gemfile to failed to be built during gem installation. This is also my problem, which I resolved by uninstalling every gems and every ruby installation, and retry from beginning.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after installing cocoapods with brew. The actual problem was that it was not linked. My problem was solved by use the recommended command `brew link cocoapods`. If an error is raised by the above command use `brew link --overwrite cocoapods` to force linking

Comment: Excellent !! This worked great in a Mac with a M2 processor.